# tomcat initialization is failed from Eclipse Servers Tab in Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am developing my java web application using Eclipse IDE
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627
Using Java-1.8, when i run my application using configured tomcat(Tomcat-7) in Servers Tab in Eclipse, Getting following error:
This same setup is working in **MyEclipse**(Purchased Version)
I am not able to find the problem with Eclipse, Could some body throw light on this problem.I don't know why it is not working in Eclipse.

when i run my application using configured tomcat(Tomcat-7) in Servers Tab in Eclipse, Getting following error:

```
SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path D:\sso-test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf/.keystore due to D:\sso-test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)

Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [D:\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [D:\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint adjustRelativePath
WARNING: configured file:[D:\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf/.keystore] does not exist.
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'sslProtocols' to 'TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2' did not find a matching property.
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 7 2015 17:14:55 UTC
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.62.0
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_45-b18
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Build\SRDM2.3.1.8189.99\SRDM2.3.1.8189.99\SRDM\Svr\tomcat
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Build\SRDM2.3.1.8189.99\SRDM2.3.1.8189.99\SRDM\Svr\tomcat
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\test\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Build\SRDM2.3.1.8189.99\SRDM2.3.1.8189.99\SRDM\Svr\tomcat\endorsed
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Users/msnaidu/Desktop/eclipseFindbugs/eclipse/jre/bin/client;C:/Users/msnaidu/Desktop/eclipseFindbugs/eclipse/jre/bin;C:/Users/msnaidu/Desktop/eclipseFindbugs/eclipse/jre/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Users\msnaidu\Desktop\eclipseFindbugs\eclipse;;.
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8085"]
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8086"]
Jul 27, 2015 7:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8086]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8086]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:173)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyAgreement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.isEcAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$KeyExchange.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getSupportedCipherSuiteList(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.getSupportedCipherSuites(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.<init>(JSSESocketFactory.java:148)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation.getServerSocketFactory(JSSEImplementation.java:47)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:390)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:649)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:86)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by a trusted signer!
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyPolicySigned(JarVerifier.java:289)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.loadPolicies(JceSecurity.java:316)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:261)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:48)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:78)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:76)
    ... 28 more
```

Note: This tomcat server which was added to severs tab in eclipse is customized for our application.

Comment: make sure that you have installed have only at one place, or if not then check path pointing to java

Comment: @GirdharSinghRathore, it(tomcat) is installed only once and java path is also pointing correct path, and the same setup is working in MyEclipse but not in Eclipse

Comment: Hello @GirdharSinghRathore, Please look into the above error log, which is updated at the first line. I think it is because of Eclipse version